# Referencing Two Separate Variables by One Name/Call

Tags: lua, roblox

I am new to Lua and am not sure if this is even possible.

Referencing two separate variables by one name/call,
i.e,

local pieces = game.Workspace.Part1 *In Addition to* game.Workspace.Part2

Both are specific objects, not values.

Comment: `local pieces = { game.Workspace.Part1, game.Workspace.Part2 }`?  Specify what *in addition to* is supposed to mean.

Comment: I am wanting to make a function to fire on either Part1 or Part2 using one variable to represent both.

Answer (score 1):

short answer:

## No

What you want to do is not possible in Lua, or in any other programming language I know of. What you want to achieve however, can easily be done.

The most straight-forward solution would be to just check your condition for either of the two values. If you need to do this often, you could make a function that checks the condition on both values, and if it happens with many different values, you can even write a function that returns another closure that checks your condition for two upvalues.

If what you care about is not so much easily checking a condition for both values, but to store them together in a semantically meaningful way, you can just put both of them in a table like `{first = game.Workspace.Part1, second = game.Workspace.Part1}`, and apply your condition to its elements `first` and `second` instead of the object itself.

Comment: Thank You! I'm very new to scripting but after reading your answer its starting to make sense why it's not possible.